Is there some medical insurance jargon term to designate the cost that a patient owes a medical provider?
Assume an individual in the United States went to a medical provider. A few weeks later, the claim is processed by the individual's medical insurance, and the insurance informs how much individual owes the medical provider. This corresponds to the cost after the medical plan's share is deduced from the medical plan's discount price.
E.g., that is cost 21.73 USD below and is referred to as "share":

Is there some medical insurance jargon term to designate that cost? Share sounds rather vague.

It depends on the reason for the charge.
In USA law, insurance policies may have an agreed charge called a deductible (in the UK this is known as an excess). This charge is paid before the insurance pays anything out over and above that amount. For example, if you agreed to a deductible of $500 and your medical bill was $600 then you would pay the $500 and they would pay $100.
However, leaving aside any deductible (or if there isn't one), if the charge is made to the patient because the insurance does not fully cover the claim, this charge is called a co-payment (or co-pay). If it is a calculated percentage of the medical bill then the patient's share can be called a coinsurance. Informally, these may also be referred to as out-of-pocket expenses or out-of-pocket costs.
As these things are part of the policy that the policyholder agreed to, I think "your share" on the example bill you showed seems pretty clear. It's good to be free of jargon.
